# Difference between float* and vector<float>

Tags: c++

What is the difference between

```
    float* x = new float[SIZE];
```

and

```
    vector<float> x(SIZE);
```

although both of them take SIZE integers space in memory, and using vector allows the usage of helpful helper functions, what if I don't need to use the vector functions.
Would it be better to use `float*` or `shared_ptr<float>` instead of `vector<float>` from performance and memory wise !?

Comment: _'Would it be better to use float* instead of vector<float> !?'_ Definitely not! It's vice versa.

Comment: Totaly agree with @πάνταῥεῖ. At least use smart pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you explain why it is vice verse please !?

Comment: @OmarSebres Because using raw pointers and explicit memory management with `new()` and `delete` is strongly discouraged in c++ programming. Otherwise your question is too broad. There are a lot of significant differences. You should check the documentation of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: If `SIZE` is a constant, you may prefer a plain array, `float x[SIZE];`

Comment: If `SIZE` is constant, you should be considering `std::array`. I believe it has minimal (possibly zero) runtime overhead, but makes various programming tasks much easier.

Answer (score 2):

When vector< float > goes out of scope its memory automatically gets free'd.

When the float* goes out of scope you'd better have stored the pointer somewhere because otherwise you have a memory leak.

See [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<float> x(SIZE);
```

This is a list of floats where elements can be appended or removed after creation. It also automates memory management

```
float* x = new float[SIZE];
```

This is a C-level manual allocation of a fixed-size array. The C++ equivalent is

```
std::array<float, SIZE> x;
```

If you don't need a dynamic array, `std::array` usually fits your needs. (Note however that `std::array` is a C++11 thing and not supported by older compilers.)

Answer (score 0):

The `vector` provides the possibility to grow and shrink, which is not the case for the array. Furthermore, the size of the `vector` can be read with a member function, which is impossible for the array.

Answer (score 0):

Vector is a class wrapping your array.
There are both benefits and drawback from this:

### Benefits:

- Vector will automatically grow with the amount of values you store in it
- Vector has boundary-checking and will be more verbose safe if you have problems in your code
- Vector has much more methods and operators to access and modify your elements such as  push_back()
- Will automatically be deleted when out of scope, you do not have to delete it manually

### Drawbacks:

- Vector will generally be slightly more slow than an array as there will be an additional level of abstraction added
- Compilers will find it harder to optimize your code

In general, if you are not doing high-performance-computing I would **always** use vector instead of an array.

Comment: I'd like to see figures on the drawbacks. Certainly, in non-optimized builds `vector` will be slower; but it's irrelevant to measure the performance of non-optimized builds in most cases. I would think that in most cases it would be a tie, except perhaps in heavy numerical computations... but even then...

Comment: Vector, used with iterator or even better with `foreach` will be as optimized as "raw array". Unless maybe when the array size is known at compile time. But in that case use `std::array`.

Comment: Both of your drawbacks are plain wrong.  STL is designed to optimise well. The performance of vec[i] and arr[i] are identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
float* x = new float[SIZE];
```

This allocates an array of SIZE number of float elements, for example, if SIZE is 10, it would allocate array of 10 floats, and can be accessed as x[0], x[1], ...x[9]. No boundary check, i.e. if you access beyond 9, error / exception won't be genarated.

```
vector<float> x(SIZE);
```

allocates a vector of SIZE number of float elements, it can grow in size as well. here also, for example, if SIZE is 10, it would allocate vector of 10 floats, and can be accessed as x[0], x[1], ...x[9]. Also, other vector helper functions can be used. A similar member function, vector::at, has the same behavior as this operator function, except that vector::at is bound-checked and signals if the requested position is out of range by throwing an out_of_range exception. 
Ref: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5b%5d/)

Answer (score 0):

> what if I don't need to use the vector functions.

Then don't use them. A vector offers operations for manipulating a sequence of values through, so it is probable that if you need a raw pointer, you *could* use a vector instead.

> Would it be better to use float* instead of vector !?

That depends on what problem you are trying to solve; Generally you will find that problems you have with managing a sequence of values tend to be similar in scope, and using a vector to handle them, is much better than reinventing the wheel every time (and probably doing do poorly).

In practice, I have found a single project where using a vector was prohibitted, and that was a performance-critical server system (which had been developed, profiled and optimized for more than ten years). Unless you are writing performance-critical software, you probably will want to use a vector. For that matter, if you are writing that kind of software, you may want to use vectors as well.

> Would it be better to use float* instead of vector !?

Basically, if you need to ask, use a vector :)

It would not be better [to use float*]. A vector solves a large number of reoccuring problems, that you usually do not think about (and don't want to, and shouldn't have to).

Among them are an exception-safe implementation, buffer overflows, memory leaks and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `float*` is a buitin whereas `std::vector<float>`  is a class for holding multiple objects. `float*` is a pointer to an object of float type. That's why you can assign a pointer to an array of floats with `new`, so that the pointer points to the first element of the new array. Another difference would be that you have to `delete[]` an array that you allocate with `new[]` whereas `vector<float>` is allocated/resized dynamically and deallocated by it's destructor.